# « Les deux pick-up » ou « leurs pick-up »?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation, reformulation

Les deux cols bleus (préposés aux travaux et à l’entretien de la ville) auraient pu laisser plus d’espace entre

…les deux pick-up garés en sens inverse l’un de l’autre, à moitié sur la chaussée dans chacune des directions. Cela aurait évité que les deux voies n’en deviennent ?[qu’] une et de perturber la circulation.

…leurs pick-up garés en sens inverse l’un de l’autre, à moitié sur la chaussée dans chacune des directions. Cela aurait évité que les deux voies n’en deviennent ?[qu’]une et de perturber la circulation.
D’autres tournures qui me viennent en tête:

Les deux cols bleus auraient pu distancer davantage les deux/leurs véhicules…

Les cols bleus auraient pu espacer davantage les deux/leurs véhicules…

N’hésitez pas à me proposer d’autres tournures plus claires et élégantes.

Note: Les pick-up prennent plus de place sur les voies, le dessin n’est pas à l’échelle.

[image]

Comment: C'est courant d'appeler des gens *cols bleus* au Canada ? Ici, c'est plus un vocabulaire de statisticien ou de journaliste.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, c’est courant. Les cols bleus désignent, en général, les préposés aux travaux et à l’entretien de la ville.

Comment: @jlliagre seems like a literal translation of *blue collar (worker)*, and English term widespread in North-America... although perhaps a bit politically incorrect by modern standards (as it points to their inferior position to *white collars* - college educated/management/etc.)

Comment: I wonder, why singular *pick-up* is used here (rather than *pick-ups*).

Comment: @RogerVadim If this was a “pure” French compound noun, the traditional rule is to only pluralize the part(s) that are semantically plural and not verbs. For example: *des oiseaux-mouches* (multiple birds, all of which are like flies), *des coffres-forts* (multiple coffers, all of which are strong), *des arcs-en-ciel* (multiple arcs in a single sky), *des gratte-ciel* (multiple things scratching a single sky, but verbs don't change so it's not “grattent”). There's no real rule for how to apply that to an imported word though. Modern French also allows just sticking an S at the end in any case.

Comment: "en sens inverse l’un de l’autre, à moitié sur la chaussée dans chacune des directions."  : On ne sait pas spontanément s'ils sont tête-bêche sur le même côté (donc dans chacune des directions) ou s'ils sont de chaque côté de la route, un dans chaque sens de circulation.

Comment: @pirela Tu as raison, merci pour ton commentaire!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comme  les  employés sont deux à travailler on peut supposer que "leur  au pluriel" indique qu'ils ont  chacun un    véhicule  mais cette supposition assez logique ne vaut  pas la certitude  immédiate d'un "les  deux".

[Français canadien]

> Les deux cols bleus  auraient pu laisser plus d’espace entre
> **les deux** picks-ups **que** dans chacune des directions de la chaussée ils ont garés à moitié sur l'asphalte en sens inverse l’un de l’autre.

[Français]

> Les deux préposés/employés à la voirie  auraient pu laisser plus d’espace entre
> **les deux** camionnettes **que** dans chacune des directions de la chaussée ils ont garées à moitié sur l'asphalte en sens inverse l’un de l’autre.

> [pas  trop clair ; "n'en devenir une"  et "n'en devenir *qu*'une", qui  rappellent "n'en faire qu'une", ne sont pas corrects.]
> Les deux cols bleus  auraient pu laisser plus d’espace entre
> **les deux** picks ups **que** dans chacune des directions de la chaussée ils ont garés à moitié sur l'asphalte en sens inverse l’un de l’autre.
> Cela aurait évité que les deux voies n’en deviennent ?[qu’] une et de perturber la circulation.

[Une autre possibilité (termes canadiens) ; je ne trouve pas utile de mentionner que les véhicules sont en sens  inverse.]

• Les deux cols bleus, lorsqu'ils ont garé les deux  picks ups en chevauchement  sur les  bords opposés de la chaussée et à seulement deux   mètres  l'un de l'autre  auraient pu comprendre qu'un espacement de plusieurs dizaines de    mètres était nécessaire, pour permettre au trafic un débordement (qui, à un angle bien ouvert, aurait été) plus facile et  plus rapide.

Comment: La dernière refonte que vous m’avez suggérée est excellente, je ne trouve rien à redire. En revanche ma phrase que vous avec reprise en la modifiant et en y ajoutant un « que » est, à mon sens, discutable: je ne parviens pas à la comprendre avec les modifications que vous lui avez apportées.

Comment: @Pretzel Essayez  de supprimer « dans chacune des directions », puis transformez « que » en « qu' ». Un  exemple de plus : « le  champ  que   chaque jour  ils voient se dessécher de  plus en plus sera bientôt comme une terre brûlée.  ». Il  me semble  qu'un complément de lieu (ou de temps) peut  être  placé   après le relatif objet.

Comment: @Pretzel Il semble certain qu'elle soit  plus  claire en plaçant « chaussée » avant.  Voyons ce  que vous en pensez maintenant.

Comment: Merci beaucoup 

Answer (score 1):

*Les cols bleus auraient pu éviter de garer leurs [camionnettes](https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872572) aussi près l'une de l'autre.*

Comment: Si on parle canadien français camionnette est recevable, mais pas en français : une camionnette est fermée tôlée alors qu'un pickup a un espace ouvert à l'arrière .

Comment: @pirela Un Canadien français n'est pas français mais Le français canadien est du français. Ma réponse s'applique à une question clairement orientée canadien français, sinon, je n'aurais pas utilisé *cols bleus* jamais vraiment utilisé ici pour désigner des employés municipaux. On aurait aussi c'est vrai dit *pickup* ou peut-être les plus courants *camions*, *camions à plateau*, *camions-plateau*, *camionnettes à plateau* chez nous.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that using *leurs* here is redundant by the French standards: just like French tend to say *j'ai mal à la tête* rather than *j'ai mal à ma tête*.

Note the difference with English, where one tends to use possessives rather than simply definite article, and *their pick-ups* would be likely more natural.

*Disclaimer:* Neither French nor English are my native languages.

Comment: If who owns the pick-ups is not perfectly clear from *les* (which I don't think it is in this case) you should use *leurs*.

Comment: @PeterShor this is a valid point.